# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, only prints first line

Tags: java, arrays, printing, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I am making a dungeon game in Java. I have created a method that stores a map in a 2D array. The array looks like this:

```
[[#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #],
[#, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., #],
[#, ., ., ., ., ., ., G, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., E, ., #],
[#, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., #],
[#, ., ., E, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., #],
[#, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., G, ., ., ., ., ., ., #],
[#, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., #],
[#, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., #],
[#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]]
```

I am now trying to write a function so that I can print out the map in the game. So far I came up with this:

```
public void printMap(char[][] map) {
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; i++) {
            System.out.print(map[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

However I am getting this error message after the first line is being printed out.

```
#########Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
```

Why am I getting this error message? How can I prevent it in the future?

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Don't read a blog, write one! Frustration relief.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for(int j=0; j < world[i].length; i++){
//      ^    ^                    ^
//      J    J                    I <- No! Bad dog :-)
```

You may want to get your variables a little more consistent.

By incrementing `i`in the `j` loop, you're near guaranteeing that you'll go beyond the end of the `world` array ("near" because that may not happen if one of the "sub-arrays" has a size of zero, but that's unlikely to be the case here, based on your input data).

Answer (score 5):

You're incrementing i instead of j in your j loop. What I don't get, however, is why it would crash after only one line. I presume you have more than simply 1 item in your first array, no?

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing i instead of j in your nested for loop:

```
  for(int j=0; j < world[i].length; i++){
                System.out.print(world[i][j]);
            }
```

change to:

```
for(int j=0; j < world[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(world[i][j]);
        }
```